# Reset all controls to initial state in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight application with a huge searchform(that form is Grid), lots of various elements inside of it(comboboxes, textboxes etc. ). If needed all data for this controls is populated from LoadDate event. My requirement is to make a button which resets all elements inside this grid and returns them in the state as they were after the LoadDate event.

Is it possible to reload only this Grid containing number of controls?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

Is somebody have interest in this, i solved this problem looking over all elements in search form and resetting them according with their type. [Here is link to answer on this question](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/648452.aspx)